# Can I access $data within a jquery call in an if-binding in Knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a foreach binding and I want to display and item only if it is not already on the page, I seem unable to reference the current element within jquery

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: fixtures">
        <tr>
           <!-- ko if: $("th:contains($data.date)").length == 0 -->
           <td data-bind="text: date">
           <!-- /ko -->
           </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: What about `<!-- ko if: $("th:contains(" + $data.date + ")").length == 0 -->`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to build your jQuery selector with string concatenation `+` :

```
<!-- ko if: $("th:contains(" + $data.date + ")").length == 0 -->
```